# Using a function with an array as input in C

Tags: c, arrays

I'm trying to write a program which asks the user to insert a series of number to make an array and then, using a function, calculate the sum and the mean of the elements of the array. The problem is that when I use the function in the `main` the output of sum and mean are both 0. And if I just use `arr[n]` without `&` I got other errors, why is that?

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int sum_and_mean (int arr[], int n);

    int i;
    int n;
    int arr[100];

int main(){

    printf("How many numbers do you want to insert?");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    if((n > 0) && (n <= 20)){
        for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
            printf("Insert a number:");
            scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
        }

        printf("The array is:\n");
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
            printf("%d\n", arr[i]);
        }
    }

    else {
        printf("Error: number must be between 0 and 20");
    }

    sum_and_mean(&(arr[n]), n);

    return 0;
}

int sum_and_mean (int arr[], int n){
    double sum = 0;
    double mean;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
        sum += arr[i];
    }
    printf("The sum of the elements is %lf\n", sum);
    mean = sum / n;
    printf("The mean of the elements is %lf", mean);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expression `&(arr[n])` is a pointer to the `n`:th element in the array, which is outside of the initialized portion of the array.

You want to pass a pointer to the *first* element of the array: `&arr[0]`, which can also be expressed as plain and simple `arr` (arrays naturally *decays* to pointers to their first element).

Comment: I would add that the sum and the mean evaluated by the sum_and_mean function both equal to zero likely because the memory you are accessing from the nth element to the nth + n element is full of zeros. I suggest to try the same code with a smaller array, let's say big about as n itself, to figure out how worse the outcome can get.

Comment: Why just passing a pointer to the first element of the array is sufficient?

Comment: @Schiele because `&arr[0]` is exactly `arr`.

Comment: Accessing an array element in C calculates the offset from the first element, so knowing that address is al you need to find the elements.

Comment: @Schiele More generically, for any array (or pointer) `a` and index `i`, the expression `a[i]` is exactly equal to `*(a + i)`. That is, when you index into an array, you add an offset. If you pass a pointer to the n:th element of your array, then inside the function you're practically doing `arr[n + i]` which of course isn't correct.

Comment: @Schiele And a little tip: If you're struggling with arrays, try drawing it out using pen and paper. Draw the array as a long rectangular box, and divide it into squares, where each square represent an element in the array. Then draw arrows to elements which represents pointers. If you do that for your array, and draw an arrow for the n:th element, then remembering that indexing *adds* to that will make it quite clear why passing that pointer would not work.

Answer (score 1):

I see something maybe have to improve in your code (I do not say about using of `arr` because @Some_programmer_dude explained very clearly).

```
else {
        printf("Error: number must be between 0 and 20");
    }

    sum_and_mean(&(arr[n]), n);
```

you should `return 0` in else statement because, if you have error, you do not need to call `sum_and_mean` function.

OT, you define `int` array, so `sum` is integer also. You should change `double sum` to:

```
int sum;
```

Thus, for `mean` value, you can multiply by `1.0` as below if you define `int sum`:

```
mean = 1.0 * sum/n
```

Comment: If I change `sum` to `int` then I don't have an exact value of `mean`

Comment: you can cast int to double by multiplying by `1.0`